# Nlog enum to integer

Tags: enums, nlog

I'm using NLog and logging events to SQL server. One of the fields logged is the log level, this is logged as a string, 'Info', 'Warn' etc. I also want to log the level as an integer value to enable me to provide better sorting when viewing the log events in a GUI.

Is it possible to convert enums to integers for inserting into a database without writing a custom layout renderer?

The configuration line to log the level into a database as a string is

```
<parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}"/>
```

Ideally there might be a conversion to integer, like;

```
<parameter name="@LevelId" layout="${level:format=tointeger}"/>
```

much like there is a `format=tostring` converter.

Comment: This days with simple usage of EF for connecting to DB and running query, I don't know why you used traditional logging way.

Comment: Coz that's just the way I roll Saeed.

Comment: I'm also using log4net for normal logs (file, eventviewer, console
), but in the case of database logs I found using EF is easier, don't need to heavy code for adding handler in special cases and there is no restriction on it, normally DB logs are vital and they need some extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a custom LayoutRenderer that I wrote for just this purpose.  I wrote it against NLog 1.0, so it might not fully adhere to NLog 2.0 conventions for LayoutRenderer (e.g. I think that GetEstimatedBufferSize is no longer used):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using NLog;
using NLog.LayoutRenderers;

namespace NLog.Extensions
{
  [LayoutRenderer("LogLevelOrdinal")]
  class LogLevelOrdinalLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
  {
    IDictionary<LogLevel, int> ordinals;

    public override void  Initialize()
    {
      base.Initialize();

      ordinals = GetLogLevels()
                  .OrderBy(level => level)
                  .Select((level, index) => new { Level = level, Ordinal = index })
                  .ToDictionary( x => x.Level, x => x.Ordinal);
    }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
      int level = 0;

      if (!ordinals.TryGetValue(logEvent.Level, out level)) level = 99;

      builder.Append(level);
    }

    protected override int GetEstimatedBufferSize(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
      return 1;
    }

    //
    // LogLevel is a static class with a static member for each of the different log levels.
    // The LogLevel ordinal is not exposed publically (i.e. an ordinal indicating the relative
    // "importance" of a LogLevel value).
    // The implementation of LogLevel.GetHashCode actually does return the ordinal, but it doesn't
    // seem right to rely on that implementation detail.
    // In the end, this LayoutRenderer is really just to allow for producing a numeric value to represent
    // a particular log level value's "position" relative to the other lob levels.  As such, 
    // We can just get all of the known log level values, order them (they are sortable), and assign our
    // own ordinal based on the position of the log level value in the resulting sorted list.
    //
    // This helper function exposes the known log level values as IEnumerable<LogLevel> so that we can
    // easily use LINQ to build a dictionary to map LogLevel to ordinal.
    //
    internal IEnumerable<LogLevel> GetLogLevels()
    {
      yield return LogLevel.Trace;
      yield return LogLevel.Debug;
      yield return LogLevel.Info;
      yield return LogLevel.Warn;
      yield return LogLevel.Error;
      yield return LogLevel.Fatal;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: In the end I went for an insert and update trigger on the table holding the log records. Based on the log level string it updates a LevelOrdinal integer field. Not ideal to have the logic buried in a trigger but the possible log levels are static enough to make it acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to convert the string to an Integer in the insert statement like so:

```
<target name="database" xsi:type="Database" connectionStringName="MyConnectionStringName" useTransactions="true">
  <commandText>
    <![CDATA[
    INSERT INTO [dbo].LogEvent
      (Time,
       LogLevel,
       Title,
       Message,
       ExceptionDetails)
    VALUES
      (@Time,
       CASE @Level
       WHEN 'Trace' THEN 0
       WHEN 'Debug' THEN 1
       WHEN 'Info' THEN 2
       WHEN 'Warn' THEN 3
       WHEN 'Error' THEN 4
       WHEN 'Fatal' THEN 5
       ELSE NULL
       END,
       @Title,
       @Message,
       @ExceptionDetails)
    ]]>
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@Time" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}" />
  <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="@Title" layout="${ndc}" />
  <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
  <parameter name="@ExceptionDetails" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
</target>
```

Comment: great option where you can't/don't want to deploy additional assemblies

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout renderer. It's very simple)

```
public class NlogLevelToIntLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        builder.Append(logEvent.Level.Ordinal);
    }
}
```